# Как правильно написать: график употребления фито- чая или график приема фито-чая?

Tags: нормы-языка

как правильно написать: график употребления фито- чая или график приема фито-чая?

Answer (score 2):

Да и так и эдак ошибки не будет.

Это рассматривается как медицинская процедура?
Тогда скорее "употребления", хотя и "прием" тоже не вызывает возражений.

Если же это понимается строго как лекарство (не процедура), тогда прием, конечно.

Ну а если это вообще из инструкции по применению, на этом чае написанной, то тут вообще без разницы. Хоть "питья" напишите.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: график приема фиточая (слитное написание!).

ОБОСНОВАНИЕ:

употребить - использовать что-л. как пищу, питьё,

принять - выпить, проглотить лекарство, пищу.

ПРИМЕРЫ:

График приема любого фиточая составляется по принципу периодичности. Неправильное употребление фиточая может привести к серьезному дисбалансу в организме.Максимальная продолжительность употребления чая – три месяца, после чего необходимо отказаться от приёма напитка как минимум на два месяца.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ:

Слова "прием" и "употребление" могут заменять друг друга, когда речь идет о самом факте использования фиточая. Если мы говорим о процедуре применения, то слово "прием" является более подходящим.